# Is it possible to set Skype to be the default dialer?

Tags: calls, skype

I am using data plan and want Skype to handle all my incoming and outgoing calls.
E.g. When I go to "People" and tap on a phone number I want Skype to do the call and not the default dialer.

Comment: It's not possible yet.

Comment: @manuel-durando This question was asked a couple years ago. Is this still the case?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to make Skype the default dialer on Windows Phone.